# When PayPal sends a REFUND message to your IPN listener, does it still carry the data for the custom fields?

Tags: paypal-ipn

I've recently wrote my IPN listener script to manage purchases for my website. Whenever a user submits a payment, there is a custom hidden field with their USER ID as the value.  I know that to identify if the message is a REFUND, it'll have the post parameters:

*reason_code = refund*

Now my question is, when PayPal notifies my IPN listener of the refunded item, will it still send the exact same post data (including my custom field so I can manage the user accordingly due to thei) that was sent when they purchased the item?

I hope I made my message clear and that it's not too confusing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,  when you issue a refund you will receive the same custom variable back in the refund that you passed over when you charged the buyer.  It will have the same value that you set.  I also just tested this to make sure there were no issues with this feature, and it is working as it should.